# Webstorm node.js auto download dependences automatically

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Is it possible in a webstorm node.js project  auto download dependances in the package.json so I dont have to run npm istall etc in the command prompt

Comment: you can install the needed dependencies using Settings/javascript/Node.js and NPM... But you need to select and install them one-by-one. Or, you can open the terminal (Tools/Open terminal) and run 'npm install' there. Unfortunately there is no way to install dependencies from the context menu action on package.json - please vote for [WEB-8776](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8776)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at **shrinkwrap**?  It allows you to;

> ...installs a package, and any packages that it depends on. If the package has a shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that. See npm-shrinkwrap(1).

http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/

and

https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html

From the second link;

> Building shrinkwrapped packages
>   To shrinkwrap an existing package:
>
> Run "npm install" in the package root to install the current versions of all dependencies.
>   Validate that the package works as expected with these versions.
>   Run "npm shrinkwrap", add npm-shrinkwrap.json to git, and publish your package.
>   To add or update a dependency in a shrinkwrapped package:
>
> Run "npm install" in the package root to install the current versions of all dependencies.
>   Add or update dependencies. "npm install" each new or updated package individually and then update package.json. Note that they must be explicitly named in order to be installed: running npm install with no arguments will merely reproduce the existing shrinkwrap.
>   Validate that the package works as expected with the new dependencies.
>   Run "npm shrinkwrap", commit the new npm-shrinkwrap.json, and publish your package.